# How to use PyWin32 to return Excel row?

Tags: python, pywin32

What I'm looking to do is search for a value in a range, and then print the Excel row in which those values exist.

Something like:

```
for cell in xl.ActiveSheet.Range('A1:A30'):
    if val in cell:
        #Print rows in which that value appears
```

This seems like something that should be pretty simple, but I'm having some difficulty thinking of how to do it.  Any help would sincerely be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like

```
import win32com.client.dynamic
from pythoncom import CoInitialize, CoUninitialize

CoInitialize()
xlApp = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)

def access_range(sheet, row1, col1, row2, col2):
    "return a 2d array (i.e. tuple of tuples)"
     sht = xlBook.Worksheets(sheet)
     return sht.Range(sht.Cells(row1, col1), sht.Cells(row2, col2))

def get_range(sheet, row1, col1, row2, col2):
    return access_range(sheet, row1, col1, row2, col2).Value


for column, data in enumerate(get_range(1, 1, 1, 10, 10)):
    for row, value in enumerate(data):
        if value == search_value:
            print "value found in column %s, row %s" % (chr(65+column), row+1)

CoUninitialize()
```

Note: The first sheet, column, and row is 1 (not 0)

Answer (score 0):

Based on user2682863's answer, what I ended up doing was the following:

```
for row, cell in enumerate(self.xl.ActiveSheet.Range('A:A')):
    if val == cell:
        row = row + 1
    print row, cell
```

This seemed to work since the value I was looking for will always be in Column A in the active sheet.